# Linux, debug, trace

Tags: linux, debugging, trace

Describe how the assert macro works and how you use it in a program, and who its output is intended for.
What advantage does the TRACE macro discussed and demonstrated in class have over debugging with just fprintf or printf directly in your code?
Explain when and how the TRACE macro output is “turned on” (enabled” or “turned off” (disabled).  If there is more than one way to do it, which is “best”, and why?
What advantage does the DEBUG macro package discussed and demonstrated in class have over debugging with the TRACE macro?

any help final tomorrow and these are extra credit questions thank you

Answer (score 3):

You really should learn to find by yourself. You are losing by asking others to do your homework without any effort (and we can't help about `TRACE` or `DEBUG`, it is not standard and we don't know the definitions you have for them).

Did you look into [assert man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/assert) and into [assert wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h) and into your `assert.h` header file (probably under `/usr/include/` at least on Linux) ??